# Error with SassError: Undefined function while starting angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am getting error while starting angular app after successful npm install.

It shows below error -

ERROR in ./src/styles.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--13-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??embedded!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js
??ref--13-3!./src/styles.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Undefined function.
╷
19 │ $marker-size-third: ceil(math.div($marker-size, 3));
│                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
╵
node_modules\progress-tracker\src\styles\progress-tracker_progress-tracker-variables.scss 19:26  @import
node_modules\progress-tracker\src\styles\progress-tracker.scss 1:9

Current package-lock.json has sass and sass-loader version -

"sass": "1.26.3",
"sass-loader": "8.0.2",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The version of sass that you are using do not support the mathematical function `div`. You are using the version `1.26.3` and that function appeared in the version `1.33.0` as you can see in their [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/math#div).

So in order to fix your issue, you have essentially 2 possibilities.

1. Bump the sass version if you can **(the preferable way)**.
2. Use the old **(and deprecated, so be aware)** `/` operator.

If you use the option number 2, your code would become this:

```
$marker-size-third: ceil( $marker-size / 3 );
```